# htaccess redirection to new params

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i want an html redirection to a different php and params, the phps are inside a subdirectory , for example, from an /subdir/index.php?thread=23-post=12 /subdir/to showthread.php?topic=23&topic=12. But isn't working this:

```
RewriteRule ^/test/index\.php?thread=(.*)-post=(.*)$ /test/showthread.php?topic=$1&topic=$2 [R]
```

Any suggestion?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't match against the query string in a `RewriteRule`. You need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` var in a `RewriteCond` and use the `%` backreference:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^thread=([^-]+)-post=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?test/index\.php$ /test/showthread.php?topic=%1&topic=%2 [L,R]
```

Note that your rule maps 2 things to the `topic` query string param.